# HttpWebRequest is very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am requesting a handler file from another handler file that returns an image, when I request my `HttpWebRequest` it takes more time to get the response. Here is my code, please help.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpCookie cookie = context.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"];
Cookie myCookie = new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
myCookie.Domain = url.Host;

request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(myCookie);
request.Timeout = 200000;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: may be you are behind the firewall ?

Comment: when i request 1st time its taking more time around 2 to 3 minutes to connect to get the response why its like this ???

Comment: That's probably some problem at the server, not in the client code. You should try to debug that.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using to test against and have you rules out if the problem is related to the infrastrucutre / network (I.E., firewalls, switches, disk io, etc.)

Comment: 6.0, no its not the problem related to network.

Comment: @ramesh I would try `request.Proxy = null;`

Comment: @L.B yeah i tried request.Proxy=null but getting the  same problem still its slow only.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your request is getting to the handler as quickly as possible. If not then it is some issue with your network. You can diagnose this with logs or debugging or whatever way you need. Use Fiddler to re-issue requests so you know exactly when it is fired and received.

If it is getting to the server and **no processing on there is taking too much time** then make sure that you are flushing and closing the response stream when you are finished writing to it. Also probably best to dispose of the responseStream object.

```
using(var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()){
   // write to the sucker

   responseStream.Flush();
   responseStream.Close();
}
```

NB If this is only on the first request (your question/answers are a little confusing) then try work out what exactly is happening at startup of the appdomain. Is there something big in global.asax - or is it doing a lot of DB work?

Comment: in global.asax am doing only DB connection

Comment: Does it take a long time both deployed and in your development environment?

Comment: no its working fine  very quickly but only thing is that my request is not getting to the handler as quickly as possible HttpWebRequest is taking around 2 to 3 minutes to get response from i.e to get an image generated by another handler why its happening like this ?? please help me

Comment: Yeah ok so where is the slow point? Is it between the browser and your server, IIS and ASP.net, Begin_request and your handler? We need more information

Comment: Could you possibly run a trace.axd on it?

Comment: no am not running trace.axd, slow point is between browser and another handler to which am requesting it to get an image ie in above code what i mentioned when the control comes  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); this line it should go to another handler to get a response ( ie an image) ,but problem is its taking more time to get response i.e 2 to 3 minutes

Comment: Ah right ok. Do you have control over this other httphandler? Can you not just wire the image directly up to the url for the other httphandler? <img src="/otherhandler.ashx?id=imageid" /> or whatever?

Comment: no controls over that actually  am generating PDF report using those images everything is working fine when i pass session cookie along with the request its taking long time to get response.

Comment: What happens if you change the timeout to something a lot smaller?

Comment: if its lot small am getting "The operation has timed out" Exception.

Comment: hi @rangitatanz are you online ? please let me know if you any idea.

Comment: No I have no idea now I don't have enough information sorry. If you can share anything more then please do. Is there a way we can see the URL you are loading? Or a snapshot of a trace?

Comment: What about using http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jan/14/Monitoring-HTTP-Output-with-Fiddler-in-NET-HTTP-Clients-and-WCF-Proxies see 'Getting Fiddler to work with .NET Client Requests' and telling us how that looks?

Comment: make sure you use ´using´ or that your requests are properly closed, otherwise you have to wait for earlier requests to time out once the max number of connections is reached.