# Slow first HTTP request with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, revit-api, revit

So I'm trying to use HttpWebRequest in my C# plugin for Revit(BIM software), to send a request to my API. But every time I try this, it takes way longer than the request would take in Chrome/Firefox/Postman.

If I send my request with Postman, it takes about 1 to 1,5 seconds. But if I send it within my application, it takes about 21 to 21,5 seconds. So it seems like there is some kind of timeout created by the HttpWebrequest, but I can't seem to figure out why this is the case.

My code:

```
static public string Get(string baseURI, Dictionary<string, string> requestParameters)
    {
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 15;
        string requestURI = baseURI;

        if (requestURI.Length != 0)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> parameter in requestParameters)
            {
                if (requestURI[requestURI.Length - 1] != '?')
                {
                    requestURI = requestURI + '&';

                }
                requestURI = requestURI + parameter.Key + "=" + parameter.Value;
            }
        }

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURI) as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Method = "GET";
        string results = string.Empty;
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        HttpWebResponse response;
        using (response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            // Get the response stream  
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            results = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }

        return results;
    }
```

I've tried the following:

- Using RestSharp
- Using HttpWebRequest
- Sending two request (the same of two different requests), where the second request only takes 1,5 seconds, as it should.
- I've tried request.Proxy = null; / ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false; / request.KeepAlive / ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 15;

I can't think of anything else, and the debugger doesn't give me any useful information on what's it doing in those 20 seconds.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519655/httpwebrequest-is-extremely-slow

Comment: Depending on the version of .NET supported, you may be better off looking at [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969382/httpwebrequest-is-very-slow

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this issue inside Autohotkey. But basically using the same ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1").

**I found out that turning off IPV6 protocol in network adapter settings on windows resolved the issue.**

So it really could be server side compatibility with IPV6.
After 20 sec fallback to IPV4 and any next request running good.
Just try turning of the IPV6.

I am going to dig more into how to force WinHttpRequest to use IPV4.

Some resources:
WINHTTP_OPTION_IPV6_FAST_FALLBACK

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/option-flags

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-option

https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/include/winhttp.h

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6555

Unfortunately this param is not compatible with WinHttpRequest.5.1 because it is param of WinHttp.

**Workaround is to disable IPV6 in registry (requires reboot)
Or much better and advised by Microsoft is to use prefixpolicy.**

https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000160803-prioritising-ipv4-over-ipv6-on-windows-10

Prefer IPV4 over IPV6

```
commandline: 
netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::ffff:0:0/96 46 4
```

Prefer IPV6 over IPV4

```
commandline: 
netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::ffff:0:0/96 35 4
```

Run As Administrator

Comment: Another option is to enable ipv6 in your API webserver.